# EntityReference is not working with AlternateKey

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-sales

I created an alternate key on Contact Entity that name is obs_key.

Here is the screenshot of the key definition.

[image: Alternate Key Definition]

and then I try to create EntityReference object like below;

```
string customerCode = entity.GetAttributeValue<string>("obs_customer_code");
EntityReference contactRef = new EntityReference("contact", "obs_key", customerCode);
```

But I'm getting errors. Error says

> **Invalid EntityKey Operation performed : Entity contact does not**
> **contain an attribute named obs_key**

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's documentation says you need to set keyname and keyvalue like below.

```
public EntityReference (string logicalName, string keyName, object keyValue);
```

[Documentation Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference.-ctor?view=dynamics-general-ce-9)

> My alternate key name is : obs_key
>
> the field dependent with alternate key : obs_id

But it didn't work. I try to set the field name, not the key name and it works.

```
EntityReference contactRef = new EntityReference("contact", "obs_id", customerCode);
```